# linear modeling question: How can I find variance for vector Y?

Tags: matrices, vectors, regression, covariance

Linear models are

$$Y_1= 2\theta_1+3\theta_2 +\epsilon_1$$
$$Y_2= -2\theta_1+\theta_2 +\epsilon_2$$

and $\epsilon_1=3z_1-z_2$ and $\epsilon_2=4z_1+z_2$, where $z_1, z_2$ are two random variance such that its  independent mean is 0 and variance is $\sigma^2$

I have written this model as $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$

$$Y=\left[\begin{matrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$X=\left[\begin{matrix} 2&3 \\ -2&1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\beta=\left[\begin{matrix} Q_1 \\ Q_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\epsilon=\left[\begin{matrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Then,

$$E(Y)=\left[\begin{matrix} E(Y_1) \\ E( Y_2) \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix} 2E(Q_1)+3E(Q_2) \\ -2E(Q_1)+E(Q_2) \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix} 2Q_1+3Q_2 \\ -2Q_1+Q_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$$$

$\epsilon_1=3z_1-z_2$ $(E(z_1)=0, E(z_2)=0)$

$E(\epsilon_1)=0, E(\epsilon_2)=0$

How can i find variance for vector Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The [variance-covariance of the vector Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is given by:

$$\Sigma_Y := Cov(Y) := \begin{bmatrix}
Var(Y_1) & Cov(Y_1, Y_2) \\ 
Cov(Y_2, Y_1) & Var(Y_2)
\end{bmatrix}$$